# What is the difference between these two lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a list of dictionaries, and in these dictionaries, there sometimes occurs a particular key. This particular key may have a dictionary as its value, and in that dictionary is a key-value pair of interest. Alternatively, the particular key may contain a list of dictionaries with contain the key-value pair of interest.
In the course of trying to get the values of interest in a list, I ran into a more basic problem: when I tried to make a list such as the one described above, I got a type error.

So I cut down a list from the real data to be as minimal as possible, and the list was created as expected. Perhaps I have simply been awake too long, but I cannot for the life of me see the difference between the list that creates and the one that doesn't.

```
bad_list = list[{'info1':'infoA', 'info2':'infoB'},
{'info1':'infoC', 'info2':'infoD', 'a_dictionary':{'of_interest':'item1','not_interesting':'item1a'}},
{'info1':'infoE', 'info2':'infoF', 'stuff_I_want':{'dlist1': [{'of_interest':'item2', 'not_of_interest':'item3'}, {'of_interest':'item4', 'not_of_interest':'item5'}],'dlist2':[{'of_interest':'item6','not_of_interest':'item7','dont_care':'about_this'},{'of_interest':'item8', 'not_interesting':'item9'}]}}]
```

gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user1\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-426-5b36ee39e1b4>", line 3, in <module>
{'info1':'infoE', 'info2':'infoF', 'stuff_I_want':{'dlist1':[{'of_interest':'item2', 'not_of_interest':'item3'}, {'of_interest':'item4', 'not_of_interest':'item5'}],'dlist2':[{'of_interest':'item6','not_of_interest':'item7','dont_care':'about_this'},{'of_interest':'item8', 'not_interesting':'item9'}]}}]
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

but:

```
good_list = [{u'_score': 22.789707, u'symbol': u'RP4-669L17.10', u'_id': u'ENSG00000237094', u'query': u'ENSG00000237094'},
{u'pfam': u'PF03715', u'name': u'NOC2 like nucleolar associated transcriptional repressor', u'_score': 22.789707, u'symbol': u'NOC2L', u'go': {u'CC': [{u'term': u'nucleus', u'pubmed': [16322561, 20959462], u'id': u'GO:0005634', u'evidence': u'IDA'}, {u'term': u'nucleoplasm', u'pubmed': 20123734, u'id': u'GO:0005654', u'evidence': u'IDA'}], u'MF': [{u'term': u'chromatin binding', u'pubmed': [16322561, 20123734], u'id': u'GO:0003682', u'evidence': u'IDA'}, {u'term': u'transcription corepressor activity', u'pubmed': 16322561, u'id': u'GO:0003714', u'evidence': u'IDA'}]}, u'query': u'ENSG00000188976', u'_id': u'26155'},
{u'pfam': u'PF00858', u'name': u'sodium channel epithelial 1 delta subunit', u'_score': 22.79168, u'symbol': u'SCNN1D', u'go': {u'CC': [{u'term': u'plasma membrane', u'id': u'GO:0005886', u'evidence': u'IDA'}, {u'term': u'plasma membrane', u'id': u'GO:0005886', u'evidence': u'TAS'}]}}]
```

creates the expected list without dictionaries.

What is different about the structure of these two lists that makes one legal and the other not? I have a feeling I'm missing something silly, but I just can't see it.

Comment: Are you sure this is a minimal example that reproduces the problem? You have not included any code, but two list objects

Comment: Yes, just running those two list creations is all I am asking about. "good_list = [...]" creates as expected, and "bad_list[...]" throws an error. I'm trying to understand what is bad about "bad_list"

Comment: After formatting your `bad_list`, I can declare it perfectly fine... https://repl.it/CqFs

Comment: why do you say `bad_list = list[...]` instead of `bad_list = [...]`

Comment: Oh, that's the problem. Oops :) Still... It isn't minimal

Comment: Because I've been awake too long @DanielLee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `list[]` to construct a list. It doesn't construct a list. It tries to extract an element from the concept of a list. I think what you meant was `list()` but that's just more verbose and less clear.

`[]` gets an item from an object. `list[]` tries to access an item from the *list data type*.

`list[1]` is like saying "Okey, get the first item from the list." The interpreter asks "Which list?", and you respond "the very concept of a list". And then the interpreter responds with a error saying "the very concept of a list isn't a list".

---

## In Depth

Saying `some_object[index]` is equivalent (syntactic sugar) for `some_object.__getitem__(index)`. So if a datatype wants to let you subscript (`[index]`) it, the datatype will define a `__getitem__`.

But the type of the type (yes - even types have types) don't want you to be able to subscript types themselves, so the type type doesn't define a `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 1):

> type' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

As the error suggest, In the first one, the part `list[<object>]` is the problem here.

You are trying to index by an object, not an integer and hence the error.

Just cut down the `list` part and you are fine.

For example, below one will work quite fine.

```
bad_list ={'info1':'infoA', 'info2':'infoB'},
{'info1':'infoC', 'info2':'infoD', 'a_dictionary':{'of_interest':'item1','not_interesting':'item1a'}},
{'info1':'infoE', 'info2':'infoF', 'stuff_I_want':{'dlist1': [{'of_interest':'item2', 'not_of_interest':'item3'}, {'of_interest':'item4', 'not_of_interest':'item5'}],'dlist2':[{'of_interest':'item6','not_of_interest':'item7','dont_care':'about_this'},{'of_interest':'item8', 'not_interesting':'item9'}]}}
```

Comment: Oh man, I feel really silly. Should I just delete this question?

Comment: @JamesHanks no. that may lead to a question ban.

Comment: "You are trying to index by an object, not an integer and hence the error." that's not the central problem. The central problem is that the OP is trying to index a list datatype

Answer (score 0):

bad_list uses the list func, but attempts to subscript it:

```
bad_list = list['h'] 
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, \
in <module> TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: I think you mean `list` function? Or function object?